# How to implement Y-Δ conversion?

Tags: engineering

There seems no built-in support for Y-Δ conversion (electrical engineering).
Any idea on how to implement this function?

Comment: Please expand the question to include a description of the Y-Δ conversion (or a link to one) and an example problem to apply it to. It would also be good to include your own implementation attempt - otherwise it can appear as if you've made no effort to tackle the problem yourself.

Comment: If the network is represented as a graph then you may use the [YTYGraphTransforms](https://github.com/mikepierce/YTYGraphTransforms) package.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own functions to perform the transformations. Below I show two functions using the transformations shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

The function `D2Y` is for converting Delta network to Y shaped network. It takes the three resistor value as its arguments and gives out the corresponding value for Y network. Similarly `Y2D` does the other way round.

```
 D2Y[ra_, rb_, rc_] := 
 1/(Total[{ra, rb, rc}])*Times @@@ Reverse@Subsets[{ra, rb, rc}, {2}]

 Y2D[r1_, r2_, r3_] := 
 Total[Times @@@ Subsets[{r1, r2, r3}, {2}]]*(1/{r1, r2, r3})
```

You can use the function as follows:

```
 D2Y[10, 20, 30]

(*{10, 5, 10/3}*)

 Y2D[10, 20, 30]

(*{110, 55, 110/3}*)
```

Comment: Compact versions for fun: `D2Y = ##/{##}/(+##)&; Y2D = Tr[##/{##}]/{##}&;`

Answer (score 2):

and more in detail

[image]

```
g1 = 1/(1/R13 + 1/(R12 + R23)) == R10 + R30;
g2 = 1/(1/R12 + 1/(R13 + R23)) == R10 + R20;
g3 = 1/(1/R23 + 1/(R12 + R13)) == R20 + R30;
```

Delta network

```
Solve[{g1, g2, g3}, {R12, R13, R23}]
```

Y shaped network

```
Solve[{g1, g2, g3}, {R10, R20, R30}]
```

[image]